# Problem with MySQL storage of a Craigslist parse

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, craigslist

I'm using MagpieRSS to parse a Craigslist feed. The "title" field is:

> ***BUYING ALL BRAND NEW BLACKBERRY IN ANY QUANTITY BOLD~JAVELLIN~ONYX
>   (Gramercy) $100000

and I'm using

```
if( preg_match( "/\(*\)*\d+$/", $title, $matches ) )
```

to figure out the price. `$matches[0]` should have the price, if I'm not mistaken. However, when I put it in my MySQL table (DOUBLE datatype), it comes in as 100. It seems to only take the first 3 digits after the $. I've run this through `preg_match` checkers all over the web, but nada.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a basic case of debugging. What does the full, generated query that inserts the row look like?

Comment: Try to use DECIMAL MySQL datatype to store price. Your regex is not very good but should work.

Comment: INSERT INTO resultset (search_id,title,price,source_url) VALUES ("1","***BUYING ALL BRAND NEW BLACKBERRY IN ANY QUANTITY BOLD~JAVELLIN~ONYX (Chelsea) $100000","100,000.00","http://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/ele/1532363555.html")

Comment: Wow.. I see my problem. Damn it. A little point in the right direction and I'm on my way. Thanks! =)

Comment: what are you going to do when the title is like "10 little indians in 9 vases for 8 dollars"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't look like it should work. Given the following title:

> ***BUYING ALL BRAND NEW BLACKBERRY IN ANY QUANTITY BOLD~JAVELLIN~ONYX
>   (Gramercy) $100000

If you wanted to just get the 100000 value, then I'd use:

```
/\$(\d+)$/
```

Comment: The problem with this will be if there are other $'s in the string, no?

Comment: This will match any number after a dollar symbol at the end of a string only. Without knowing enough about the rest of your titles, I can't say how reliable it is. For example, if there are spaces between the symbol and the numbers (or other data between the numbers and the end of the string), then it won't match.